# What's the difference between Graham-Denning model and Harrison, Ruzzo, Ullman (HRU) model

Tags: access-control

I have trouble understanding the differences between these models.

My understanding:

HRU and Graham-Denning are both computer security models that define the interaction between subjects, objects and actions.

They are similar in that they all define a set of subjects, a set of objects and a an access control matrix.

They are different in regards to how to modify, and who can modify these rights.

It is said that the HRU model is an extension of Graham-Denning model.

> Harrison-Ruzzo-Ullman extended this model by defining a system of protection based on commands made of primitive operations and conditions.

And HRU model is more flexible, and is able to describe several access control approaches.

While Graham-Denning model is said to be more limited, with a few problems.

HRU model has six primitive operations:

- grant right to subject and object pair
- delete right from subject and object pair
- create subject
- create object
- delete subject
- delete object
  Which are then form transitions: sequences of basic operations.

While Graham-Denning defines eight basic rules:

- create an object.
- create a subject.
- delete an object.
- delete a subject.
- grant right.
- delete right.
- transfer right.
- read right.

**First Question:** What does this difference provide? Does it give more flexibility? (For example, transfer right in G-D can be a transision of deleting and then granting of a right in HRU)

I also know that in G-D each subject has an owner, which can be itself.

**Second question:** Does the same hold true in HRU?

And when a subject is the owner of itself, then it can delete other subjects access to itself, which is considered undesirable.

**Third question:** Does HRU solve this problem? (Is it a problem?)

Am I wrong and what can be added?

Comment: Have you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRU_(security) ?

Comment: @tom-k Yes, of course.

Comment: Then you should be able to add more than the sentence you copied from wikipedia. :) You should narrow your question down to a **specific** problem you have. There can be added a lot more.

Comment: @TomK. You are right. Edited the question to more specific details. Thank you.